# How right answer come from

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am just doing exercise I have a very interesting question here

```
6 men can do a piece of work in 12 days. How many men are needed to

do the work in 18 days?

A. 3 men

B. 6 men

C. 4 men 

D. 2 men
```

Though I know right answer might be `C` but how ? Is it like per person day division is two ? or which equation or formula we use for it ?

Comment: The work takes $(6)(12)$ person-days.

Comment: Think of a measurement of labour required to complete the task as *"Man Days"*.

Comment: I guess you assume the number of man-days is independent of the number of men - an assumption notoriously false for software work (the famous Mythical Man Month book by Fred Brooks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track (and there is more than one way to conceptualize this).

First figure out how long it would take one person to do the work: if $6$ people take $12$ days, then it would take $1$ person $6\cdot 12 = 72$ days, so you could say the job takes $72$ person-days. (you might be more familiar with the term "man-hours"; here we have the same idea, only in terms of days rather than hours (and made gender-neutral))

Thus, if you want to get it done in $18$ days, it will take

$$
\dfrac{72 \textrm{ person-days}}{18 \textrm{ days}} = 4 \textrm{ people}
$$

Comment: 72/18 = 4 , but 72 are days , why you use equation like person-days ?

Comment: It takes $6$ **people** $12$ **days**, so the units are person-days.